# What Minimum Azure Features Requires for running ASP MVC with elastic search as a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, elasticsearch

I know about elastic search and run a server in Command prompt in Windows 10 and Work in ASP.NET MVC.

I just want to host in Azure platform. as i have been using shared hosting with SQL server before. so i Need help

What will be minimum requirement or features i have to get to host asp.net mvc application compatible with mobile apps ( providing Apis , not for large scale only for 1 , 2 application ) , with elastic search running at the end ?

Do i have to get virtual machine , documentDB etc features.

Comment: There are a lot of variables that come into play here.  It's difficult to answer without all of the relevant information.  I have a website that runs ASP.NET MVC and I'm struggling to answer this question myself and my site gets in excess of around 20,000 hits a day.

Comment: at least you can tell the minimum features so i will start and after some time i can add more features or extend it / transform it according to hits.

Comment: Maybe you're right.  What features do you need?  What functions does your application facilitate?  What does it need in order to work at the moment?

Comment: it actually saves the user data in database and search from that data only. Not at a large scale for publicly use. Organization about 100 employees will use. Data will be inserted in elastic search and generate a google sheet document and will have application. Data will be increase time to time

Comment: Sounds good.  Is there any requirements for file storage?

Comment: No 1gb would be enough for now

Comment: I'm not really your man for this one.  I was asking questions in a hope that we could get all of the information so that someone who knows could provide their insight.  At the moment it isn't clear what the question really is or what the full requirements are.  In fact, it could be out of the scope for this platform.  I believe that Azure have a customer service department, maybe you should give them a call for advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple solutions to your scenario.

**Using ElasticSearch**

1) To run ElasticSearch you need an Azure Virtual Machine, this could be one from the Marketplace, like, an Ubuntu Server. The size of the VM will depend on the load that it has to manage, maybe you can work with an S1 or you might need an S2. In this case, it's your responsability to expose the network interfases for the elastic search service.

2) For your Web App, you'd need an Azure Web App (App Services). Depending on the load, you can go with an S1/S2 and define your [scaling strategy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/) if you need to. There are plenty of tools to measure how your Web App is handling load (NewRelic / AppInsights).

3) Finally, it depends on your Data, but you might need to store it in a persistent storage, like Azure SQL or Azure DocumentDB (depends on the nature of the data) in case you need to rebuild your Elastic Search indexes (and thus reindex from the persistent store).

**Using Azure Search**

1) Instead of Elastic Search, you can use [Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/), it will simplify the whole scenario, since it's SaaS (Soft-as-a-Service) and you don't need to maintain and configure a VM, just use the service API from your Web App. Under the hood, it's basically Elastic Search/Lucene with added things.

2) You still need the App Service for your Web App.

3) You still need the persistent storage (Azure SQL, DocumentDB) in case you need to reindex your information or create new indexes.

Basically it all boils down to 3 services (VM/Azure Search + App Service + SQL/DocumentDB) + the Network usage that your App consumes, that's how you'd calculate your costs.

We are currently using both solutions on our products (ElasticSearch for an ELK Logging platform / Azure Search for our main client products) and both work well, but it depends really on your wallet and the kind of implementation times you have, the Azure Search approach might be faster.